# Program LED from Linux Zynq Embedded

Tags: c, linux, embedded, xilinx, gpio

I am trying to blink an LED on a Xilinx zc706 board using Linux.

https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/ek-z7-zc706-g.html

I have been able to toggle a GPIO in Linux using methods explained here

https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2012/11/access-gpio-from-linux-user-space.html

in a basic user space program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{

    int valuefd, exportfd, directionfd;

    printf("GPIO test running...\n");

    exportfd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);

    if(exportfd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open GPIO to export it\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    write(exportfd, "971", 4);
    close(exportfd);

    printf("GPIO exported successfully\n");

    directionfd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio971/direction", O_RDWR);

    if(directionfd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open GPIO direction it\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    write(directionfd, "out", 4);
    close(directionfd);

    printf("GPIO direction set as output successfully\n");

    valuefd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio971/value", O_RDWR);

    if(valuefd < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot open GPIO value\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("GPIO value opened, now toggling...\n");

    while(1)
    {
        write(valuefd, "1", 2);
        write(valuefd, "0", 2);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

My question is if there is some sort of way in software to map the GPIO number I would use in Linux to the GPIO that controls the LED. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "map" in this context? Are there multiple pin naming schemes involved?

Comment: I am not sure. It would be very easy for a baremetal application. I am not sure how Linux abstracts pin locations though? In baremetal, I could just write to the pin address but with Linux, it is not that simple

Comment: The code  you show uses  the kernel's GPIO driver to access the pin as a device file. This is  how you do it in Linux. What is wrong with that  solution?

Comment: could that not be any GPIO? How in the process of Xilinx embedded design would I know that that GPIO 971 corresponds to the GPIO number for toggling the LED and not some random pin?

Comment: You simply need to look at the schematic, to figure out which pin on the chip the LED is connected to. I tried, but they require login for the [download](https://www.xilinx.com/member/forms/download/design-license.html?cid=396436&filename=zc706-schematic-xtp215.zip) and that was too much. This is not specific to the chip being a Zynq, it's just a question of how the board was designed. Often you'd discuss this with the board designer, or just view the schematics they've created.

Comment: @JohnFrye *"How ... would I know that that GPIO 971 ... not some random pin?"*  -- If the pin is already in use (e.g. by a driver), then the export would fail to create the pin directory.  Note that an LED connected to a pin can be declared as a [gpio-leds](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/leds/leds-gpio.txt) in the Device Tree.  The LED name would show up in **/sys/class/leds/**, and you could turn it on or off by opening and writing to the **brightness** file (instead of **value**).  Inspect **/proc/device-tree/leds** to see if that was already done for you.